# C# open new tab if it's not already opened

Tags: c#, .net, url, redirect, browser

I am working on desktop app in WPF, with button to open browser.

At this moment I am using this code only :

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.website.com");
```

But I am wondering if it's possible to check if website is already opened and then just redirect to that tab, instead opening new tab with that URL.

Comment: That line just launches the system's default browser, anything that happens in the browser is probably out of your hands.

Comment: In that case, is there a way to get a list of all opened tabs in browser? Maybe iterate through them and check if the one i am interested in is active?